# Como integrar Eclipse PDT com Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eclipse, pdt

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como integrar de fato a IDE Eclipse PDT, com `Laravel` 5.x... É necessário algum plugin? Tem algum passo a passo para me passar? Eu abri um projeto já existente, porém o Eclipse está identificando alguns arquivos com erro, até mesmo arquivos criados através do `php` `artisan`...